# Using CONCAT in query not working

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have:

two input types for searching.  One a text field for city, state, zip, type.  The other is a select drop down for a "type" of business search.

I want to return the the results for the "location" input along with the "type" input.  So, if the user searches for New York NY, 83745 in the "location" input and Walgreens in the "type" input only Walgreens in New York NY, 83745 is returned.  **HOWEVER**, using the CONCAT method in my query limits this.  The user can use commas and spaces in the "location" input.  But, the "type" input is disregarded all together.  Both search types will only work together if I take out the CONCAT and use basic single WHERE clauses.  So, how can I have the CONCAT's and the `"AND style LIKE '%$search_type%'";` work together?

```
$query = "SELECT street, city, state, type FROM location
  WHERE 
  CONCAT(city, ', ', state, ', ', zip_code) LIKE '%$search_location%'
  OR CONCAT(city, ' ', state, ' ', zip_code) LIKE '%$search_location%'
  AND type LIKE '%$search_type%'";
```

Comment: Now ... that *can't* be good index utilization. It is also very restrictive about user input. Did you know `AND` has a higher precedence then `OR`? `x OR y AND z` is `x OR (y AND z)`?

Comment: It's a shortened query.  Either way I want to figure it out

Comment: Looks like you should have brackets around the two `LIKE` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Boolean Full-Text Searches
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
$query = "SELECT street, city, state, type FROM location
WHERE 
MATCH ($search_location) AGAINST (CONCAT(city, ' ', state, ' ', zip_code) IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND type LIKE '%$search_type%'";
```

I think this example will not work, but if you will read about this you will figure it out

Comment: `match (city, state, zip_code) against ('$search_location' in boolean mode)` will work, assuming `ALTER TABLE location ADD FULLTEXT(city, state, zip_code);` has been done.

Answer (score -1):

this syntax is not supported by mysql. concat can merge strings, not columns.

this is your best option, I believe:

```
$query = "SELECT street, city, state FROM location
  WHERE 
  ( city LIKE '%$search_location%' or state  LIKE '%$search_location%' or zip_code LIKE '%$search_location%' )
   AND style LIKE '%$search_type%'";
```

for proper match to work:

```
ALTER TABLE location ADD FULLTEXT(city, state, zip_code);

$query = "SELECT street, city, state FROM location
    WHERE match (city, state, zip_code) against ('$search_location' in boolean mode)
    AND style LIKE '%$search_type%'";
```

Comment: How can I allow funky punctuation in the location input?

Comment: what do you mean by "funky"? what should be done is use "mysql_real_escape_string($field)", once the connection is open

Comment: This answer makes no sense. `CONCAT` will work perfectly well on column references - what do you even mean by "sql objects"?

Comment: well, indeed, and thanx. It never occured to me that concat could work on the sql itself. I edited the other part.